# MySQL Counting Checkins Per Hour Per Membership Subtype

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

I'm new to MySQL, so bear with my potential screw-ups. I need to create a query that displays our different membership subtypes and how many times each subtype has checked in per hour on a given day. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
SELECT 
 customers.CUSTOMER_CUSTOM_TYPE AS Subtype,
 COUNT(CASE
    WHEN checkins.POSTDATE BETWEEN '%17:00:00' AND '%17:59:59' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS '5pm',
 COUNT(CASE
    WHEN checkins.POSTDATE BETWEEN '%18:00:00' AND '%18:59:59' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS '6pm',
 COUNT(CASE
    WHEN checkins.POSTDATE BETWEEN '%19:00:00' AND '%19:59:59' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END) AS '7pm'
FROM
 checkins,
 customers
WHERE
 checkins.CUSTOMER_ID = customers.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND checkins.POSTDATE LIKE '2017-10-05%'
GROUP BY customers.CUSTOMER_CUSTOM_TYPE;
```

For brevity's sake, I've only included three hours. I keep getting the same numbers for each hour, despite the POSTDATE change. The setup of the table is correct:

[MySQL Membership Subtype Checkin/Hour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPgWg.png)

In other simpler queries, I've counted checkins by counting a customer's CHECKIN_ID for a given timeframe. Customers are given different, unique checkin ID's every time they check in. Am I going about this correctly? Is there a simpler way? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `COUNT()` should be `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to use proper `join` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the the `from` clause.

A simpler version of your query might be:

```
SELECT cu.CUSTOMER_CUSTOM_TYPE AS Subtype,
       SUM( hour(ch.POSTDATE) = 17) AS `5pm`,
       SUM( hour(ch.POSTDATE) = 18) as `6pm`,
       SUM( hour(ch.POSTDATE) = 19) as `7pm`
FROM checkins ch JOIN
     customers cu
     ON ch.CUSTOMER_ID = cu.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE DATE(ch.POSTDATE) = '2017-10-05'
GROUP BY cu.CUSTOMER_CUSTOM_TYPE;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases.  They make the query easier to write and to read.
- Don't use string comparisons for dates and times.  This extracts the date for comparison (there are alternatives if you have an index on that column).
- `LIKE` patterns don't work with `BETWEEN`.  I replaced it with the simpler `HOUR()`.
- This uses a MySQL shortcut that treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context -- so `case` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too attached to the structure of the current table, might I suggest a redesign of the data structure which might greatly simplify this information.

It looks like you are trying to keep track of three key points of information: `customer_id`, `room`, and `check_in_time`. The `checkin_id` you mention, then, could be a PRIMARY KEY value generated on insertion into this table. Instead of sorting this information into a chart-like table by time in the first place, there is great value in just keeping track of these three pieces of data.

Next, instead of many cases: look to utilize a `GROUP BY` statement. In the case of needing to delineate by room, then hour it would look a little something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as num, hour(check_in_time) as hr
FROM checkins
Group By room, hr
```

This will return the count of checkins per hour for all rooms at all hours. If you are looking to break it down by day or year just add the time functions to the Select and Group statements.